# Android capturing a new image and setting it to imageview. causes Exception

Tags: android

Hai i am working on an Application where the user have to upload a image either by picking an image from gallery or taking a new image from camera.When testing the app works fine when i pick an image from gallery.but when i capture a new image using camera the app crashes with exception 
**caused by: java.lang.nullpointerexception: attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.uri android.content.intent.getdata()' on a null object reference**

Declaring intent :

```
 final CharSequence[] dilogitems = {"Take Photo","Select from gallery","cancel"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder diloguebuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(addlog.this);
        diloguebuilder.setTitle("Add Photo");
        diloguebuilder.setItems(dilogitems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
            {
                if (dilogitems[i].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (camIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
                    {
                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"image.jpg");
                        camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(file));
                        startActivityForResult(camIntent,TAKE_PICTURE);
                    }
                }
               else if (dilogitems[i].equals("Select from gallery"))
                {

                    Intent pickgallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    pickgallery.setType("image/*");
                    if (pickgallery.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
                    {

                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickgallery,"Pick an Application"),SELECT_FROM_GALLERY);
                    }

                }
                else if (dilogitems[i].equals("cancel"))
                {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        diloguebuilder.show();
```

on Activity result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==TAKE_PICTURE&&requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            try {
                File tempimage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"image.jpg");
                personImg.setImageBitmap(decodefile(tempimage.getAbsolutePath()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(addlog.this, "Error Loading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
      else if(requestCode== SELECT_FROM_GALLERY&& resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            image = data.getData();
            try
            {
             persinbitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),image);
                personImg.setImageBitmap(persinbitmap);
                personImg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(addlog.this, "Error loading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

decodeFile() Method:

```
private Bitmap decodefile(String absolutePath)
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        int reqheight = persinbitmap.getHeight();
        int reqwidth = persinbitmap.getWidth();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absolutePath,options);

        int height = options.outHeight;
        int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height > reqheight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqheight);
        }

        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqwidth) {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqwidth);
        }


        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absolutePath, options);
    }
```

Here is the Log cat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.mrudu.accounts/com.example.mrudu.accounts.addlog}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.mrudu.accounts/com.example.mrudu.accounts.addlog}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2995)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.mrudu.accounts/com.example.mrudu.accounts.addlog}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3626)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.mrudu.accounts.addlog.onActivityResult(addlog.java:104)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6161)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3622)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
```

*Thanks in Advance...*

Comment: Post your stack trace ?

Comment: @JhamanDas i just added logcat data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536603/null-pointer-after-capturing-image-using-android-camera see the accepted answer

Comment: @JhamanDas Thank you...